# How to handle cash advance travel expenses in database?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm implementing a software solution for a company. As part of its business processes they give cash advances to its employees when they get on a business trip, let's say 1000 dollars. Those 1000 dollars are withdrawn from one of the cash registers available and the transaction is registered to the database as an expense so at the end of their turns cashiers are able to justify the 1k missing.

Then, sometimes the employee who travels spends just part of the money he was given, let's say 500 on gas, 200 on hotel and 100 on meals, so 800 out of the 1000 he was given.

So here's the situation I'm dealing with: those three expenses (gas, hotel and meals) need also to be registered individually when the employee comes back from his trip for two reasons:

1. To store the expense under the right expense concept so we can then query the database and see how much the company spends on every concept.
2. To match the money given to the employee as cash advance for his travel expenses with his actual expenses. So a total of four transactions would be performed: three expenses and one income, the 200 the employee didn't used, to match the original 1K.

Up to this point everything is fine regarding the cash advance transaction: 1000 dollars were given and 1000 dollars where justified, 800 in expenses and 200 as the money back. The problem is, the original 1000K still exist as an expense, so the total balance would be -600: 1800 spent and 200 income, which is obviously not correct.

I've thought of two alternatives:

1. Subtract the travel expenses (800) from the original cash advance expense (1000). This way, the final balance is right (0). But that would mean modifying an old expense entry which in turn will affect that days cash closing if for some reason it needs to be consulted in the future. I'm not sure if this is actually a bad thing to do since the final balance will match the actual money, it just feels wrong to mess with an old entry that will no longer represent what actually happened that day.
2. Treat cash advances as a special entity, not as an actual expense. This new entity will have the following fields: withdrawn_money, money_back and spent_money. When calculating the cash closing for that day the outcomes would be the sum of expenses plus the sum of cash advances withdrawn_money thus leaving the cash closing intact. Later when the actual expenses are presented they will go directly to the expenses table but at the same time being registered as a cash_advance spent_money new entry. This way we can keep under control how much of the withdrawn money is returned and at the same time save the actual expenses under the right expense concepts for future querying.

Cash advances not being considered as actual expenses make sense to me since the money is in employees hands so technically is not an expense yet.

Alternative 2 sounds better to me but I'm still trying to find the most appropriate implementation. It would be of great help to get opinions of more experienced developers and database designers on subjects like this.

Thanks in advance for your time and I would gladly clarify anything if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with the double-entry accounting this situation looks like this:

1. there is a transaction from account 501 (which refers to the money in cash) using the currency as a reference/article to account 422 (which refers to the company staff) using the employee as a reference/article
2. when the employee comes back:

   - if he has paid with credit card only and has not used the cash - you make a reverse transaction (from account 422 to account 501)
   - otherwise for each receipt/invoice he brings back - you make a transaction from account 422 (using the employee as a reference/article) to account 609 (which is for other expenses - and then referencing the appropriate expense)
   - if the employee does not have a receipt/invoice for some of the money - it stays in account 422 and on the next salary payment you make a smaller transaction for his salary and compensate with a transaction from account 422 to account 604 (which is the payroll) to clear the remainder

Comment: Ok, your scenario clears things up for me: is not like I have to consider the cash advance as an expense but as a transaction between two accounts (register and employee) that needs to be cleared (left in zero) after the event... thanks for your time.

Comment: The main goal of accounting is to know where the money is at any given point in time - so you just store the fact of movement by using transactions between accounts.

Comment: Do you know of any resource online where I can learn more about this kind of processes in general? I mean, those codes you used seemed as some kind of convention or something I think would be helpful to learn... or are they arbitrary values you choose?

Comment: These are the codes which are normally used by the accountants in my country. In your country they are probably different. Take a look at just 2 examples https://strategiccfo.com/standard-chart-of-accounts/ and https://www.accountingcoach.com/chart-of-accounts/explanation and also https://www.principlesofaccounting.com/chapter-2/the-general-ledger/

Comment: Generally the account numbers do not matter unless you are using the data to officially report to the government - in this case they require you to stick to the official standard General Ledger. Generally you would like an account for each business entity so that you can represent activities with transactions. Usually accounts have only 1 dimension to specify parameters/attributes - e.g. the account 401 represents contragents (40101 for suppliers and 40102 for clients) so each transaction to/from 401 specifies the contragent as a parameter.

Comment: There is accounting software (I have built such) which allows multi-dimensional accounts - e.g. when you get raw materials from the warehouse and start producing a product you may have a transaction like `source is account 301 - which is the warehouse - and dimension/parameter is metal profile MT104, while destination is account 601 - which is unfinished products - and dimension 1 is the raw material, dimension 2 is the client order, dimension 3 is the manufacturing operation (e.g. cutting/drilling/painting) and dimension 4 is the employee performing the cutting/drilling/painting"

Comment: Of course, not every company needs to record such level of details - but when they need it, they can record almost all details into a single transaction with multi-dimensional accounts. While a classic software with only single-dimensional accounts will need several transactions in order to represent each of the extra dimensions through several single-dimensional accounts.

Comment: Thank you very much, your insight makes me think that maybe I should change my schema a little bit. This kind of information is what makes stackoverflow so helpful.